# Python. How to remove an object from list

Tags: python, list

So I'm learning basic game programming and I have this Bullet class which of course are the class for the bullets in game.

```
bulletGroup = [i for i in bulletGroup if i.buly < screen.get_height()]
for shot in bulletGroup:
    shot.buly -=3
```

This is what I did so I could remove the bullets which have already passed the screen frpm abpve/ However it doesn't seem to reduce the length of my list so that tfirst line of code might not be working. So how do I do a check for a list of objects and then remove all those I want to estroy.

EDIT:
Yes I checked if the objects' buly in the list by printing them, and they were definitely less than the screen height. Yet they are still part of the list? All of this are on the game loop btw. So every tick should have bulletGroup renewing for those runaway bullets.

Comment: Are you sure there are objects that fail the condition? Can you give some example data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are subtracting `3` from `buly` each time, so it will never be greater than `screen.get_height()`.

Depending on how your game works, you should either compare `buly` against `0`:

```
bulletGroup = [i for i in bulletGroup if i.buly >= 0]
for shot in bulletGroup:
    shot.buly -= 3
```

Or add 3 to `buly` instead:

```
bulletGroup = [i for i in bulletGroup if i.buly < screen.get_height()]
for shot in bulletGroup:
    shot.buly += 3
```

Comment: OH CRAP! I'm so stupid somehow my brain didn't notice but was confused by cartesian and the coordinate system used in games. -_- It now works. Thaks for that! Can't believe I spent several minutes on that one.

Comment: Glad it's working now :) One other thing to remember is that you might need to account for the height of the bullet if you're doing the first option (something like `if i.buly >= -bulletHeight`).

Comment: I thought of that but I thought it didn't really matter since it's just a circle about 5px in diameter. :)

Answer (score 0):

You might also find that it's better to keep a fixed pool of bullets rather than adding them to the list and then removing them. Instead, give them a flag to 'deactivate' them so they don't get updated or drawn every frame and then 'activate' a new one when you need more.

If you constantly create and destroy bullet objects, you'll be causing a lot of garbage collection and creating periodic pauses in your game. A fixed pool of objects prevents that from being a problem, and lets you avoid accidentally creating too many at once.